# What does "pas de deux" mean in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> The pas de deux of immune tolerance.

Recently, I read an article with the title written above and this article is about immune rejection in the case of organ transplantation, its mechanisms that cause this, and how to have immune tolerance against rejection.

But I am not able to find correlation between "pas de deux" and immune tolerance.

> Pas de deux meaning--(in ballet) a dance for two people, usually a man and a woman

`

Answer (score 12):

It must be a metaphor. In a ballet pas de deux, the two dancers interact in complex ways.

So there must be two things that are interacting.  Without reading the context I would guess "the transplanted organ" and "the host immune system" are interacting, or "dancing together".

Answer (score 0):

The titles means,

> The balance between A and B in immune tolerance.

Please note that I am not a doctor, so I have no idea what A and B are!  For example, it might mean

> The balance between Cost and Deaths in immune tolerance.

Or

> The balance between Oxygen and Carbon in immune tolerance.

If you want an opinion, it is an ***extremely bad title***.

My guess is the author was "trying to be clever" but, in fact, simply has no clue about the phrase they are using.

All good?